# Two apparently different definitions of a path object in the model category theory

Tags: category-theory, model-categories, cofibrations

I have a question about a **path** object in the context of model categories. 
For what Hovey says see the first snippet below.
But [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02650.pdf) on page 9 the definition is different:
Henry says (see the second snippet below) that the composite of
$P_X Y \twoheadrightarrow Y \times_X Y \twoheadrightarrow Y$ is an acyclic fibration, but Hovey says
$Y \twoheadrightarrow P_X Y$ is a weak equivalence.

What is the relationship between these two definitions?

First snippet (Mark Hovey):

[image]
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Second snippet (Simon Henry):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, note that they apply in different contexts, in Hovey we make no assumptions about whether or not $Y$ is fibrant, and in Henry, we have a relative notion defined for a fibration $Y\newcommand\fib\twoheadrightarrow \fib X$.

Also a note, since it's not explicit in Henry,
$Y\to P_XY$ is a weak equivalence by 2-of-3, since $Y\to P_XY\fib Y\times_X Y \to Y$ composes to the identity map, so it's equivalent to assume either $Y\to P_XY$ or $P_XY\fib Y\times_X Y\fib Y$ is a weak equivalence.

Now in the common context, $X=*$, $Y$ fibrant, we can ask whether the two definitions agree, and in fact they do, by the observation in the previous paragraph.